# An Efficient Way to Add Two Attributes' Information Into a Single Core Data Entity with a Table View

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, if-statement, nsfetchedresultscontroller

I have a basic App Premise - allow the user to information to 4 text fields and have that information accurately displayed in a Table View, using FetchedResultsController and Core Data.

I have a problem getting one entity with two attributes to update appropriately.

My entities are:
Transaction (isGiven attribute)

Occasion (dateOfEvent, title attributes)

Person (name attribute)

Item (itemType attribute).

Person and Item do not matter here. In the Save Method of the View Controller, I call my Occasion class, pass it the entered dateOfEvent and title. In this class, what I want to achieve is:

- Check if the title exists. If not, create one. If yes, return it.
- Check if the date exists. If not, create one. If yes, return it.

The date is currently a string (which will be changed to a NSDate later - I'm testing this out first).

I have created a complex If statement, but it's just not updating the Table view appropriately. Let's look at some code:

**Occasion**

```
+ (Occasion *)occasionWithTitle:(NSString *)title andEnteredDate:(NSString *)date inManagedObjectContext:(NSManagedObjectContext *)context
{
    Occasion *occasion = nil;

    // Creating a fetch request to check whether the name of the person already exists
    NSFetchRequest *eventRequest = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:@"Occasion"];
    eventRequest.predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"title = %@", title];
    NSSortDescriptor *eventSortDescriptor = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"title" ascending:YES];
    eventRequest.sortDescriptors = [NSArray arrayWithObject:eventSortDescriptor];
    NSFetchRequest *dateRequest = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:@"Occasion"];
    dateRequest.predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"dateOfEvent = %@", date];
    NSSortDescriptor *dateSortDescriptor = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"dateOfEvent" ascending:YES];
    dateRequest.sortDescriptors = [NSArray arrayWithObject:dateSortDescriptor];
    NSError *error = nil;
    NSArray *occasions = [context executeFetchRequest:eventRequest error:&error];
    NSArray *dates = [context executeFetchRequest:dateRequest error:&error];

    if (occasions)
    {

        if ([occasions count] == 0)
        {
            occasion = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Occasion" inManagedObjectContext:context];
            occasion.title = title;
            if ([dates count] == 0)
            {
                occasion = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Occasion" inManagedObjectContext:context];
                occasion.dateOfEvent = date;
            }
            else
            {
                occasion = [dates lastObject];
            }
        }
        else
        {
            occasion = [occasions lastObject];
            if ([dates count] == 0)
            {
                occasion = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Occasion" inManagedObjectContext:context];
                occasion.dateOfEvent = date;
            }
            else
            {
                occasion = [dates lastObject];
            }
        } 
    }
    else
    {
        // handle error
    }
    return occasion;
}
```

The save method calling this is:

```
Transaction *transaction = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Transaction" inManagedObjectContext:context];
Occasion *enteredOccasion = (Occasion *)[Occasion occasionWithTitle:self.occasionTextField.text andEnteredDate:self.dateTextField.text inManagedObjectContext:context];
transaction.occasion = enteredOccasion;
```

The fetchRequest in the TableView showing just the "Occasion Names" is:

```
NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Occasion" inManagedObjectContext:managedObjectContext];
fetchRequest.entity = entity;    
NSSortDescriptor *sort = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"dateOfEvent" ascending:NO];
fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = [NSArray arrayWithObject:sort];
```

When I select an Occasion Name, I get segued over to another controller which shows me all information about that occasion, including Person names, amounts (things related from the Transaction Entity), so my fetchRequest is:

```
NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Transaction" inManagedObjectContext:managedObjectContext];
fetchRequest.entity = entity;    
NSSortDescriptor *sort = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"occasion.dateOfEvent" ascending:NO];
fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = [NSArray arrayWithObject:sort];
fetchRequest.fetchBatchSize = 20;
NSFetchedResultsController *theFetchedResultsController = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:fetchRequest managedObjectContext:managedObjectContext sectionNameKeyPath:@"occasion.dateOfEvent" cacheName:nil];
```

I know something is not quite right with the Occasion if statements - perhaps I only need one insertNewObjectForEntityForName because it's creating all sorts of inaccurate results in the Table View - like creating multiple occasions, dates, etc.

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `if` statement logic is wrong. you do need only one `insertNewObjectForEntityForName` to avoid duplications.

To create an `Occasion` only if one does not exist with that `title` OR `dateOfEvent`
the logic should be:

```
NSFetchRequest *r = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:@"Occasion"];
r.predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"title = %@ OR dateOfEvent = %@", title,date];
NSArray *matched = [context executeFetchRequest:eventRequest error:&error];

if (matched) {
    if ([matched count] == 0) {
        occasion = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Occasion" 
                                                 inManagedObjectContext:context];
        occasion.dateOfEvent = date;
        occasion.title = title
    } else {
        occasion = [matched lastObject];
    } 
} else {
    // handle error
}
```

This mean that only one occasion is allowed for a specific date OR title, which does not make a lot of sense in the real world.
If you want to make sure that an event does not already exist for that `dateOfEvent` AND `title`, simply replace the `OR` with `AND`

**Note:** my solution does not take into account that if an existing occasion is found it is the one matching the `title` (I assumed it does not matter).

**Edit:**
After reading your comments, it is not quite clear to me what is it you try to accomplish?

If you need your `Occasion` entity to be unique on the title (group occasion occurrences by title), and have many dates you will need to change your model in order to support this functionality.

Add an `OccasionOccurrence` entity to your model with a `date` (and any other attribute you need for the occurrence).
instead of your `date` attribute on your `Occasion` entity add a to-many relationship to `OccasionOccurrence`

now, when creating an `OccasionOccurrence` (instead of `Occasion`) check if any records exist for:

```
NSFetchRequest *r = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:@"OccasionOccurrence"];
r.predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"occasion.title = %@ AND dateOfEvent = %@", title,date];
```

if the fetch return any results than this is a duplicated event (or not if you have many birthdays on the same day).

As you can see, it is not clear what are you trying to accomplish.

Comment: thank you very much for your reply - that really makes sense because I thought my entire "Occasion" class was pretty wrong - that really helps. I changed it to the AND statement as you mentioned, it's not finding the matching event.. so with the exact code above, but with the AND, if I add transaction 1 with Occasion Birthday and date of Today, save it, it's all good.

Comment: If I add another entry with Birthday and date of Today (different person), it works and is all good. The moment I add a new transaction with Birthday, but a different date like Yesterday, it produces two separate Birthday objects in the Table View.. the first one has the latest transaction and the other has the other two transactions - is there a way to slightly modify the code so that it checks "if event exists, return it. if date exists, return it. If neither exist, create both, if one exists, create it but return the other etc? I just want to sure I rid of any duplicates in the Table View

Comment: It looks like it's just implementing your last statement: Note: my solution does not take into account that if an existing occasion is found it is the one matching the title (I assumed it does not matter). - I feel it's just one line or two away

Comment: @amitsbajaj I have edited my question, but it is still not clear what is it you what to accomplish. please provide more information on your task

Comment: Thanks Dan for the update and sorry for the confusion. I just want to be able to return an existing Occasion if it already exists, or create a new one if it doesn't. I want the same with the dates; return an existing one if it exists or create a new one if it does not. But also a combination of the two; there could be an existing date but a new Occasion, or an existing Occasion and a new date.. I would like that flexibility, without duplicates... is it possible? I hope this makes sense - thanks again

Comment: The original if statement in your response almost worked, but it treats the date and the occasion title in the predicate as one.. either an AND or OR, but there's no way to say, new title, existing date.. or new date, existing title.. that's why I was trying to create my complex if statement that kind of treats the two independently..

Comment: Hi Dan - problem solved. I followed you advice and created a new Entity just for the dates and now with the combination of your code and a few lines I had working previously, this is set up exactly how I want it to be. Thanks again - I really appreciate your assistance with this!

Comment: @amitsbajaj How would you detect that an `Occasion` exist (by title, by date, by both, what is the primary key?). You statement: "I just want to be able to return an existing Occasion if it already exists, or create a new one if it doesn't. I want the same with the dates;" does not make sense, if you already detected that an occasion exists  or not, why do the same for `date` on the `Occasion`? my AND predicate should give you a state where only if an `Occasion` with the same name and date exists it is returned otherwise create a new `Occasion`